# How to read dbf file in python and convert it to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dbf

I am trying to read a dbf file using `simpledbf` library and convert to to dataframe for further processing.

```
from simpledbf import Dbf5
dbf = Dbf5(r"C:\Users\Prashant.kumar\Downloads\dbf\F1_1.DBF")
df1 = dbf.to_dataframe()
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error.
[image]

I tried to find a solution but couldn't find a resolution, nor I can find an alternative way to convert the dbf file to a dataframe for post processing.

Here is the file
https://mega.nz/folder/gKIBUKIa#rE7TmE5FToLzCblMhLLFbw

Is there a way to read this dbf to python as a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dbfread` instead of `simpledbf`:

```
# pip install dbfread
from dbfread import DBF
from pandas import DataFrame

dbf = DBF('F1_1.DBF')
df = DataFrame(iter(dbf))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     RESPONDENT                                         RESPONDEN2 RESPONDEN3 STATUS  FORM_TYPE  STATUS_DAT SORT_NAME PSWD_GEN _NullFlags
0             1                             AEP Generating Company                 A          0  1990-01-01                       b'\x00'
1             2                              ALABAMA POWER COMPANY                 A          0  2000-05-03                       b'\x00'
2             3            Alaska Electric Light and Power Company                 A          0  1990-01-01                       b'\x00'
3             4                        Alcoa Power Generating Inc.                 A          0  1990-01-01                       b'\x00'
4             5                   THE ALLEGHENY GENERATING COMPANY                 A          0  1990-01-01                       b'\x00'
..          ...                                                ...        ...    ...        ...         ...       ...      ...        ...
389         538                                    DesertLink, LLC                 A         -1  2020-11-17                       b'\x00'
390         539  NextEra Energy Transmission MidAtlantic Indian...                 A         -1  2020-12-03                       b'\x00'
391         540                      Wilderness Line Holdings, LLC                 A         -1  2020-12-15                       b'\x00'
392         541                McKenzie Electric Cooperative, Inc.                 A         -1  2021-04-19                       b'\x00'
393         542               LS Power Grid New York Corporation I                 A          0  2021-08-27                       b'\x00'

[394 rows x 9 columns]
```